# Bulk rename files in GCP cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, file-rename, bulk

I have thousands of files in GCP cloud storage
At location 'gs://my_bucket/my_location' and want to add same text before all file names.

Ex. It is %.jsonl and want to do customer_%.jsonl

I could not see bulk rename option in GCP.

It would be a great help if I get something on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cloud Storage Objects are not renamed. To change the name you must copy the object. and delete the original. There is no bulk operation for that procedure.

Comment: Agree with @JohnHanley. You can find in Python a rename function on Cloud Storage, but if you go in the source code, it's a copy and a delete operation. Parallelize your code and be patient.